# Why not use ‘finding’?

Tags: word-usage

> What we have to do now is find why the accident happened.

Why can *is* add a verb here (*find*)? And I think *find* should be *finding*.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with this sentence, but not the problem you thought. This is a bit of a lazy construction, and has an implicit **to**; it's also missing the word "out," which should be present:

> What we have to do now is **to find** (out) why the accident happened.

To *find something* is to locate it. To *find something out* is to learn or discover it. The latter is the meaning intended here.

The infinitive form **to find** is correct because the phrase is acting as a noun phrase: it is the *thing* that "has to be done now." As such it is grammatically abstracted from the rest of the sentence, and the verb is not conjugated.

Comment: I don't agree that the word _out_ "should" be present. It's optional, and often omitted in contexts like these. Check out [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+the+facts%2Cfind+the+truth%2Cfind+out+the+facts%2Cfind+out+the+truth&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Comment: I don't see a problem with 'to' here. From a Beatles song: _all you have to do is call and I'll be there_. Here's a thread, mentioning statistics in favour of no 'to' (which is especially impressive for AE): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/all-you-have-to-do-is-read-vs-all-you-have-to-do-is-to-read

Comment: @Alex_ander I said the "to" is implicit. I agree it can be left out, and often is, especially in spoken form.

Comment: @J.R. Interesting Ngram, but I think both the examples you picked are special cases, as "to find the truth" and "to find the facts" are set phrases. In the OP sentence I feel like "why it happened" is something that should be found _out_. It sounds strange to my ear without it.

Comment: So, 'What we have to do now is find why the accident happened' equals 'What we have to do now is to find why the accident happened'. That is to say 'to' can be omited. Is this right?

Comment: @Y.zeng: Yes, _to_ can be omitted in this construction. The question that Alex_ander linked has an explanation in the answers.

Comment: @TypeIA: _to find why it happened_ is perfectly normal to me (BrE), with or without _out._

Comment: Is this sentence right:' What we have to do now is finding why the accident happened.'?

Comment: I see this sentence in my book: **He had a big lunch despite having just had breakfast.**     So, I feel that **verb-ing = sth**. Why not use **finding** in the sentence I asked first?

Answer (score 0):

Finding wouldn't work in that sentence without other changes. You can't use a verb in it's Present continuous form after "*What we have to do now is...*"

You'd have to change the sentence to something like, "*What we have to be doing now is...*"